# iPhone Screenshot on the App Store in a WordPress website?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, web, gallery, screenshot

Inside my site where I show my iPhone Apps, I would like to show iOS screenshots like in the App Store. Is there any wordpress plug-ins or ways to emulate this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great **[Jquery](http://jquery.com/)** plug-in called **[Infinite Carousel 2](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/12/30/huge-updates-to-jquery-infinite-carousel-version-2-released/)** you could use. It has nothing to do with WordPress, but it would embed just fine in a page. [The way I'm using it](http://www.jindianzi.biz/omw/) isn't exactly what you're looking for, but the plug-in supports exactly what you need by telling it you want 2 images displayed side-by-side, or 3, or whatever, [something more like this](http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/infinitecarousel2/demo/d2.html).

Comment: This is nice, but I want it to be able to scroll on the iPhone/iPad when I touch and scroll, not on its own.

Comment: The plug-in is completely configurable. The example on the site I pointed you to doesn't move on its own, only when you tap/click for yourself. A search for 'jquery swipe carousel -sencha' (the last -term is because the Sencha stuff is only for that framework and won't help you) returns a bunch of possibilities that don't autoplay and respond to swipes, including http://matmarquis.com/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the screenshots like how they are all horizantal because if not all you have to do is add the image of the app that you took from the app store.

Comment: Yes, I would like it too look just like how it does on the app store, with the page indicators, the slide to swipe on a device, and maybe buttons on the computer.

Comment: Ok, it can be done but it is rather complicated and there isnt a word press plugin for it.